# how to decreasing the loading time of mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an app which get the data from PHP backend API.

now there are more and more people online and have chats, the messages loading time need so much time per messages(take over 10s). I would like to know how can I decrease the loading time of the loading of the message.

codes are as following, even I change the data from 20 to 5, although it show 5 messages per time, still same long loading time.

Can you guys help me check this PHP code? can I edit something to fix this issue? Thanks

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages 
  WHERE chatId = (:chatId) 
    AND id < (:msgId) 
    AND removeAt = 0 
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
```

code seems too long and not allow post here..please check in this link: paste.ofcode.org/i6rHbdVjhfscaMVVva9E9L

database table structure: 
https://www.imageupload.net/image/msg.OIVDM
https://www.imageupload.net/image/database.OIgHh

Comment: *"code seems too long and not allow post here"* - That's because it's unreasonable to expect members of this community to setup and debug *your entire application* for you. You are encouraged to do some debugging and narrow down the specific performance bottleneck you're attempting to address.  The one line of code you're showing in the question is just a SQL query. Have you confirmed that this is the bottleneck? If so, use the MySQL `EXPLAIN` syntax to profile the query and get information about its execution plan. Share that and the table structure in the question as text, not linked images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about indexes. If you set up index on column (or columns) MYSQL can search and sort questies much faster. Try adding few indexes.

I would start with columns `removeAt`, `chatId`, `fromUserId`, `toUserId`. You can also experiment with complex indexes (`removeAt` + `chatId` <-- in this order or `fromUserId` + `toUserId`).

After adding indexes run `EXPLAIN` command on your queries (eg. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatId = 5 AND id < 10 AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20`). In results you should see which indexes where possible and which index was used by MySQL.

One thing to note - do not add too many indexes ("just in case") because they will slow down adding new rows to database.

---

To add index go to table view in phpMyAdmin (structure) and select column on which you ant to add index. Then press `index` below columns: [image]
You need to add indexes one by one. If you select more than one column it will create single complex index.

Comment: i am not good at coding..if you can help me fix it will be better, anyway, thanks so much for your reply

Comment: @l l I've added description and screen.

Comment: thanks so much..but still no any ideas for fixing my issue

Comment: Maybe start with taking queries from source code and launching them one by one in phpMyAdmin to check which ones take a lot of time to run. When you will find long running queries you can then run them with `EXPLAIN` word before them to find out how those queries are run.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(chatId, removedAt,   -- in either order
      id)                  -- third
```

This index with be "covering" and perfect for the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, hence able to also handle `LIMIT 20`.

That is, it will look at only 20 rows, whereas any other index will require looking at all the rows.

More on optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql